# How nginx forwards TCP connections through domain names？

Tags: apache, nginx

I want use a domain name instead `mysql` ip address with port 80.

But, If `stream` is listening for port 80, then `http` can not continue to listen to port 80.

I hope that `stream` and `http` are listening on port 80 together, according to the different domain name to handle the request.

Please help me. Thanks !

Comment: So, what's the reason for which you **want** to use port 80 to connect to MySQL? If you analyze that reason, logically deduce is **absolutely mandatory** to connect to MySQL over port `80` then sure, let's discuss how to do it. But, if it isn't - all you need to do is drop your "wanting" to do it over port 80 and problem goes away.

Comment: As it tested, this behavior between modules is not implemented.

Comment: @Mjh Thank you for your answer.Because the non-80 port is disabled on this machine. So, I had to forward through port 80.

Comment: @Deadooshka Thanks . Do you mean that its can not forward by domain name?

Comment: Multiplexing through port 80 is bad for many reasons. How about implementing port knocking and authentication for allowing MySQL connections? If the ports besides 80 are disabled, someone did that for a reason and that someone should help you achieve MySQL connections by implementing the same security measures. If you really want to do that, search for multiplexing via haproxy through port 80.

Comment: it need an "http-gasket" for mysql like a http-tunnel or special http plugin.

Comment: @Mjh Agree with your argument, in fact, there are problems such as ssh 22 port, etc.,Well, I should change my mind. Thank you again.

Comment: @Deadooshka Yes, that's it. But I have to change the way. Thanks .